# jpanel not showing contents

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to make a generic Ok/Cancel dialog that can accept a subclassed JPanel that adds two abstract methods (void ok() and void cancel());

The idea is that when the Ok button or the Cancel button is pushed, the appropriate methods on the subclassed panel are called. However, I cannot get the main frame to show the JPanel.

here is the OkCancelFrame code. If it is run, it should show an Ok/Cancel form with the text "Now you see me".

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class OkCancelForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private OkCancelPanel okCancelPanel;

    public OkCancelForm(OkCancelPanel okCancelPanel) {
        this.okCancelPanel = okCancelPanel;
        initComponents();
        mainPanel.add(okCancelPanel);
        mainPanel.revalidate();
        mainPanel.repaint();
        pack();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        javax.swing.JPanel buttonPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        javax.swing.JButton ok = new javax.swing.JButton();
        javax.swing.JButton cancel = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        getContentPane().add(mainPanel, gridBagConstraints);

        buttonPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        ok.setText("Ok");
        ok.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                okActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(ok, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());

        cancel.setText("Cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cancelActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(cancel, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, gridBagConstraints);

        pack();
    }

    private void cancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        okCancelPanel.cancel();
        this.dispose();
    }                                      

    private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        okCancelPanel.ok();
        this.dispose();
    }                                  

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OkCancelPanel panel = new OkCancelPanel() {
            public void ok() { }
            public void cancel() { }
        };

        panel.add(new JLabel("Now you see me"));

        new OkCancelForm(panel).setVisible(true);
    }

    private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
}
```

Comment: Don't. Use. Null. Layout. It's biting you in the behind. Seriously. You're adding a component to a null-layout using container, and when doing this, if you don't set the component's size and location, it will default to 0,0 location and 0, 0 size. One solution is to set the component's bounds via `setBounds(...)` but still, you remain with use of a very inflexible layout manager that basically paints your GUI into a corner. Just don't use it.

Comment: Oops, I thought I had taken that line out. That fixed it.

Comment: What's wrong with using `javax.swing.JOptionPane` as a starting point?

Comment: @DavidPostill: indeed, it appears that the OP is creating their own JOptionPane but without some of the JOptionPane advantages -- it's not a modal dialog for one.

Comment: This class is indeed similar to the JOptionPane, but it works better for my purposes. If I were to include multiple Panels on a JOption Pane (and yes, I realize I can't do this with the current code, but will be something that happens in the final code) the calling code would need to know what to do with each one when the buttons are clicked. As it is, it just needs to know to call ok or cancel and the individual panels will take care of it from there.

Comment: I've read your comment above, but even after reading it, I'm still not sure why you can't use a JOptinPane for your purposes. The JOptionPane will tell you if OK or Cancel have been pressed, and since it is a modal dialog, it prevents any further use of your GUI until it has been dealt with. Please see edit to answer for an example of using JOptionPane.

Comment: The reason is because then the calling code has to know what to do when the ok button or cancel button is pushed. With my method, the calling code doesn't care what the panel needs to do when the ok button or cancel button is pushed, it simply lets the panel know which one was pushed. Take for instance a panel that modifies the number of widgets the widget object has counted. Then there is the panel that alters the current location of a truck. With my method, both of those classes simply need to return an OkCancelPanel that handles it and they could even be combined on the same frame if needed

Comment: (cont'd) also, switching a non-modal JFrame to modal JDialog is pretty trivial.

Comment: But wouldn't the calling code be in fact the objects with the counts, for instance, wouldn't it be the WidgetCountPanel that displays the OK/Cancel panel, and so wouldn't it (or perhaps better, its model) need to know what response was given?

Comment: No, the idea is that the Widget class creates a panel that can be reused anywhere that I might need to edit the Widgets so the calling code could be anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use null layouts as it is biting you in the behind. Seriously. You're adding a component to a null-layout using container, and when doing this, if you don't set the component's size and location, it will default to 0,0 location and 0, 0 size. One solution is to set the component's bounds via `setBounds(...)` but still, you remain with use of a very inflexible layout manager that basically paints your GUI into a corner. Just don't use it.

---

**Edit**
[David Postill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3536342/davidpostill) makes a good comment, that you appear to be trying to re-create your own JOptionPane, and why not simply use the JOptionPane class that is already available. You may not know that you can stuff your own JPanel (or any JComponent for that matter) into the JOptionPane. For example this code below:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class OkCancelForm2 extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 300;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;

   public OkCancelForm2() {
      JLabel label = new JLabel("What the Heck?", JLabel.CENTER);
      label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(32f));
      label.setForeground(Color.yellow);

      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      add(label);
   }

   // just for fun
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.red, 20, 20, Color.blue, true));
      g2.fillOval(0, 0, 2 * getWidth(), 2 * getHeight());
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      OkCancelForm2 mainPanel = new OkCancelForm2();

      int selection = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, mainPanel,
            "My OK/Cancel Pane", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

      if (selection == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
         System.out.println("OK selected");
      } else if (selection == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
         System.out.println("Cancel selected");
      } else {
         System.out.println("JOptionPane closed with no button selected");
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

---

Has these lines:

```
  OkCancelForm2 mainPanel = new OkCancelForm2();

  int selection = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, mainPanel,
        "My OK/Cancel Pane", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Which will stuff the JPanel-derived object, mainPanel, into a JOptionPane, and will produce this JOptinPane:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. It is working.

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class OkCancelForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private OkCancelPanel okCancelPanel;

    abstract static class OkCancelPanel extends JPanel{
       public abstract void ok();
       public abstract void cancel();
    }

    public OkCancelForm(OkCancelPanel okCancelPanel) {
        this.okCancelPanel = okCancelPanel;
        initComponents();
        mainPanel.add(okCancelPanel);
        mainPanel.revalidate();
        mainPanel.repaint();
        pack();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        javax.swing.JPanel buttonPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        javax.swing.JButton ok = new javax.swing.JButton();
        javax.swing.JButton cancel = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        getContentPane().add(mainPanel, gridBagConstraints);

        buttonPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        ok.setText("Ok");
        ok.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                okActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(ok, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());

        cancel.setText("Cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cancelActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(cancel, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, gridBagConstraints);

        pack();
    }

    private void cancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        okCancelPanel.cancel();
        this.dispose();
    }                                      

    private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        okCancelPanel.ok();
        this.dispose();
    }                                  

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OkCancelPanel panel = new OkCancelPanel() {
            public void ok() { }
            public void cancel() { }
        };

        panel.add(new JLabel("Now you see me"));

        new OkCancelForm(panel).setVisible(true);
    }

    private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
}
```